# C++ Overloading an Operator as a Class Member

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I was attempting to create a simple vector class when I encountered a problem.
This is a snippet of my code:

```
class Vector2D{
protected:
    int x, y;
public:
    Vector2D operator - (const Vector2D&);    
    friend int SumDiff(const Vector2D& obj1, const Vector2D& obj2);
};

Vector2D Vector2D::operator - (const Vector2D& param)
{
    Vector2D obj;

    obj.x = x - param.x;
    obj.y = y - param.y;
    return obj;
}

int SumDiff(const Vector2D& obj1, const Vector2D& obj2)
{
    int result;
    Vector2D obj3;

    obj3 = obj1 - obj2;

    result = obj3.x + obj3.y;
    return result;
}
```

The line `obj3 = obj1 - obj2;` is highlighted as an error. Specifically, the operator`-` in this line does not seem to take `Vector2D` objects as operands.

The same problem occurs even if the `SumDiff`function is part of the `Vector2D` class.

This code only seems to compile if the operator`-` is overloaded as a non-member function. Why?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your operator must be declared as const:

```
Vector2D operator - (const Vector2D&) const;
```

Else, you cannot use it with `obj2`, which is `const`.

As commented by NathanOlivier, you can also declare this operator outside the class as:

```
Vector2D operator - (const Vector2D& left, const Vector2D& right)
{
    Vector2D obj;

    obj.x = left.x - right.x;
    obj.y = left.y - right.y;
    return obj;
}
```

Then, you need to make it be a friend of your class (or add setters/getters), so that `x` and `y` can be accessed.

Comment: Or use standard convention and declare it as a free function.

Comment: Sorry, missed that bit somehow.

Answer (score 1):

Your `operator -` member function is not marked as `const`, which means it:

- states that it can modify the state of `*this` (the left-hand opearnd)
- therefore cannot be called with a `const`-qualified object as the left-hand operand

Since `operator -` should most certainly *not* modify either of its operands, simply mark it `const`:

```
Vector2D operator - (const Vector2D&) const;
```

Note that in general, it's usually better to implement binary operators as non-members where possible. The reason is symmetry in implicit conversions. A binary operator implemented as a member can use implicit conversions on its right-hand side operand, but cannot use them on the left-hand side one (since the operand would need the proper type to find the operator in the first place).

Since you normally also want the compound assignment operators to exist, a common pattern is to implement the non-member binary operators in terms of the compound assignment, like this:

```
Vector2D& Vector2D::operator -= (const Vector2D &rhs)
{
  x -= rhs.x;
  y -= rhs.y;
  return *this;
}

Vector2D operator - (Vector2D lhs, const Vector2D &rhs)
{
  lhs -= rhs;
  return lhs;
}
```

Finally, for use in production, consider using [Boost.Operators](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_62_0/libs/utility/operators.htm) to do most of this automatic delegation for you.